# GWT clien app hosting/deploy

Tags: apache, gwt, hosting

i want to use gwt + php, html for my new project and would like to know how i can compile/deploy the html + jscript/ajax files that gwt creates onto a non jvm server like an apache server.

1) i want to use gwt for my client side interface, now when i do that i want to make asynchronous call to the server and have php serving the data from database.
2) for that i want to know how the gwt project is compiled in eclipse then what all files from the war directory are put on the apache server etc? is there any guide for this?

all i found on the web is exaample and tutorials on using a jvm supported web server for gwt even if you dont want to use java technology on the server side.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The war folder, as you've figured out, is all of the things a Java servlet container will need to do its job. This includes the static compiled files from GWT, any images or html added to the folder, and the code that the servlet container will run.

If you are working off of a PHP server, you probably just want the compiled JS/HTML/images - these are all in a folder with the name of your GWT module. Compile the app, and copy that directory into your documents folder that is served by apache. To run the module, load the `.nocache.js` file in your html page (which may be static, or may be written out by a php file).

If you are working from a project in Eclipse, created by the Google Plugin for Eclipse, you can copy the contents of the war folder, minus the WEB-INF (which holds the Java specific stuff), and just use that. You'll then have a working html file and compiled javascript.

To make calls to your own server, use the `RequestBuilder` class - this wraps up the basic AJAX features of the browser, and gives a simple, consistent way to create and configure the request, and to get a callback when it has finished.

To deal with data, it will depend on what kind of data your PHP code is sending back to the client - GWT includes options for reading both xml and json, and since the RequestBuilder will give you the raw string sent back, you can also do your own parsing.

Lastly, remember that after you copy over the compiled module, you can run your apache server with PHP, but debug the GWT code in Java. If apache is running on port 80, the simply launch dev mode (you may wish to stop GWT dev mode from starting a server, untick the 'run built-in server' checkbox in the GWT run configuration) and load the page, with the argument gwt.codesvr=localhost:8080. This may look something like this in your url bar:

```
http://localhost/index.php?gwt.codesvr=localhost:8080
```